# OSError when running puppeteer on raspberry pi

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, puppeteer, pypputeer

I am trying to make my RP a server for some web automation tasks so I installed `python 3.7` and [pypputeer](https://pypi.org/project/pyppeteer/) (Python's version for Googlel's puppeteer). The problem is that my code that run smoothly on my OSX gives me the following error on the PI:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 45, in <module>
    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(main())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/asyncio/base_events.py", line 568, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "main.py", line 16, in main
    browser = await launch(headless=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyppeteer/launcher.py", line 311, in launch
    return await Launcher(options, **kwargs).launch()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyppeteer/launcher.py", line 169, in launch
    **options,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 756, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 1499, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
OSError: [Errno 8] Exec format error: '/home/pi/.local/share/pyppeteer/local-chromium/575458/chrome-linux/chrome'
```

The code only starts chromium in headless mode:

```
async def main():
    browser = await launch(headless=True)
    page = await browser.newPage()
    await page.goto(URL_FOR_SCRAPING)

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(main())
```

I tried to install all the Debian dependencies from [here](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/troubleshooting.md#chrome-headless-doesnt-launch) and also make `pypputeer` install chromium again like it does at first time. but nothing seems to solve this error. There is also [this Github post](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/issues/807) that doens't seem to be helpful. Does anyone know what can be done?

Answer (score 5):

Apparently the solution was to redirect chromium path in the code to some version of chromium you know is working.
so

```
whereis chromium-browser
```

and then:

```
browser = await launch(headless=True, executablePath='/usr/bin/chromium-browser') # where your chromium was, in my case /usr/bin/...
```

Comment: thanks a lot! You should definitely mark your self-reply as answer.